# Can geom_dotplot & geom_text_repel work together? (DotPlot with labels.)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I would like to create a dotplot with labels like shown in the graphic.

However I cant get `geom_text_repel` to draw lines to the correct positions if points are close together.

```
df=data.frame(name=c("A1","A2","B1","B2","B3"),value=c(1,2,2,2,2),group=c("A","A","B","B","B"))

ggplot(df,aes(x=group,y=value,label=name))+
  geom_dotplot(df,mapping=aes(x=group,y=value),binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1)+
  geom_text_repel(df,mapping=aes(segment.color="red"),box.padding = 1,max.overlaps=10)
```

[image]